# How to communicate between ASP.NET & C# Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, communication

I am in the process of developing a project that will require communication both ways between a ASP.NET website and a C# Application.

For example if I wanted to click a button on an ASP.NET webpage to retrieve the status of something.

How could I implement this communication between them?

Please note I have never used ASP.NET before, hence my question.

Comment: Need more clarity on 'from where you intend to get the status'. From the description, it looks like you need a webservice.

Comment: SignalR. Basically built for this.

Comment: please specify type of c#appliction i.e class library,console application,windows form application,web service etc

Comment: I suggest u to read tutorials of asp.net ...

Comment: I think I found what I was looking for:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406096/A-beginners-tutorial-for-understanding-Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use same database in both website and application. If you want to transfer something from application to website, like a file, then you will need a web service or WCF service. But your wish seems like a shared database by website and application.

Answer (score 1):

I think You should go through this link.....it has all the basics of asp.net and c# in very easy manner compared to all the other websites....
http://www.w3schools.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could make the C# application write data somewhere and have ASP.NET read it there. Either to a database (which makes the most sense), or to some file, like an XML or JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Storing communication on a database seems like an easy way to do it.

You could use a webservice, but that would need to be hosted by the website. The application could still poll this to write and read when needed though.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what I was looking for:

**A Beginner's Tutorial for Understanding Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)**
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406096/A-beginners-tutorial-for-understanding-Windows

Comment: http://www.nullskull.com/q/10151332/communication-between-aspnet-web-application-and-a-console-application.aspx